# How do I find coefficients and exponents for a given function with a few function values?

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

Assume I have given a function, in my problem it would be

$$ f(x) = c_1 e^{r_1 x} + (c_1 x)^3 - (c_2 x)^2 $$

and I have a list of function values $f(x)$ for x from $0$ to $20$.

How can I effectively search for $c_1, c_2$ and $r_1$ without just trial and error?

Comment: To start: If you set $x=0$ then you get the equation $f(0)=c_1+0-0$. Since you know $f(0)$ you can conclude the value of $c_1$

Comment: @Marcel are you expecting this equation to fit the data exactly or are you trying to minimize something like the squared error of the fit?

Comment: Is there noise in the data or are they exact ?

Comment: The function values are long floats, so I assume they are not 100% exact. I am trying to minimize the squared error, yes. I'm actually supposed to use Gradient Descent Optimization for this.

Comment: @Marcel, that's a good idea, I would have suggested gradient descent for any complicated regression for an inexact function

Comment: @Marcel : if you post an example of data $\left(x,f(x)\right)$, I will show you how to compute the parameters $c_1,c_2,c_3, r_1$ with a direct method (no initial guess, no iterative process).

Comment: @JJacquelin: [0.2, -0.142682939241718, -0.886680607211679, -2.0095087143494, -3.47583798747496, -5.24396052331554, -7.2690008846359, -9.50451068338581, -11.9032604272567, -14.4176327390446, -16.9998176236069, -19.6019094345634, -22.1759550265352, -24.6739776668383, -27.0479889096801, -29.2499944927101, -31.2319972651608, -32.945998641919, -34.3439993255969, -35.3779996651013, -35.9999998336943, -36.161999917415, -35.8159999589895, -34.9139999796348, -33.4079999898869, -31.249999994978, -28.3919999975061, -24.7859999987616, -20.383999999385, -15.1379999996945] for x=[0,29] (integer)

Comment: @Hugh: You can see my implementation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671524/gradient-descent-in-python-2) but it does not work

Comment: @Marcel : Sorry, I made a mistake in reading your question. Instead of $y=c_1e^{r_1x}+(c_1x)^3+(c_2x)^2$ , I wrongly read $y=c_1e^{r_1x}+(c_2x)^3+(c_3x)^2$. If it has been so, this would be the same as $y=a_2x^2+a_3x^3+be^{px}$ which can be treated with a procedure already published. This procedure doesn't work if the same parameter appears in two different terms, so cannot be applied in your case. Much more work should be necessary to adapt the procedure to your case and I have not enough time to start such a new study. Sorry again and best regards.

Comment: By the way, your numerical example is a "textbook case" since there is no scatter and the parameters are "round" numbers : $r_1=-0.7$ , $c_1=0.2$ , $c_2=-0.25$. Anyways, this doesn't change the substance of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The data provided by Marcel is :

[0.2, -0.142682939241718, -0.886680607211679, -2.0095087143494, -3.47583798747496, -5.24396052331554, -7.2690008846359, -9.50451068338581, -11.9032604272567, -14.4176327390446, -16.9998176236069, -19.6019094345634, -22.1759550265352, -24.6739776668383, -27.0479889096801, -29.2499944927101, -31.2319972651608, -32.945998641919, -34.3439993255969, -35.3779996651013, -35.9999998336943, -36.161999917415, -35.8159999589895, -34.9139999796348, -33.4079999898869, -31.249999994978, -28.3919999975061, -24.7859999987616, -20.383999999385, -15.1379999996945] for x=[0,29] (integer)

And we know that the scatter is very low, so, the data is quite exact.

This is a very particular case, since the first point $(x=0,y=0.2)$ gives a first approximate of $$c_1\simeq 0.2$$  We will see later that it's in fact an exact value.
$$y(x)=c_1e^{r_1x}+c_1^3x^3-c_2^2x^2$$

Moreover, for large values of $x$ the term $x^3$ is big. A first approximate of $c_2$ can be derived in considering as quite exact $(x=29,y=y_{29})$ and negligible the term $c_1e^{r_1x_{29}}$ :
$$y_{29}\simeq c_1^3x_{29}^3-c_2^2x_{29}^2 \quad\to\quad c_2^2\simeq \frac{(0.2)^3 (29)^3-(-15.1379999996945)}{(29)^2}\simeq 0.250000$$
$$c_2\simeq 0.500000$$
The equation to be fitted becomes :
$$y(x)-0.008x^3+0.25x^2\simeq 0.2e^{r_1x}$$
The regression for only one parameter $r_1$ is straightforward considering the linear relationship of the logarithms :
$$r\simeq \frac{1}{28}\sum_{k=1}^{k=28}\ln{\frac{y_k-c_1^3x_k^3+c_2^2x_k^2}{c_1}}\simeq -0.701379$$
Note that the numbering of the points is from $k=0$ to $k=29$, so that $x_k=k$.

The first point $(k=0)$ and the last point $(k=29)$ are not included in the sum because they where used to compute $c_1$ and $c_2$ respectively : $y-c_1^3x^3+c_2^2x^2=0$ exactly, for those two points.

The first approximate result is : $\quad c_1\simeq 0.200000 \quad c_2\simeq 0.500000 \quad r_1\simeq -0.701379$

Further calculus (non-linear regression) leads to the exact result :
$$\quad c_1= 0.2 \quad c_2= 0.5 \quad r_1= -0.7$$

That is the result prematurely mentioned in one of my comments. This answer shows how it was obtained.

Of course, this method is not valuable in all cases. This was possible only because the data is particular as noted at the beginig.